# How to show vehicles as per customers in sale.order form in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have inherited res.partner model and views and added one page named Vehicle Details as shown in below image :

[image: res.partner inherited]

Simillarly I have inherited sale.order model and views and added one field named vehicles in its form which is shown in below image :

[image: sale.order inherited]

Code for inheriting sale.order :

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class CustomSaleOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = "sale.order"

x_model_ref_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner.line', string="Model Name")
vehicle_tags = fields.Many2one('res.partner.line', string="Vehicles", domain = [('name','=','partner_id')])

@api.onchange('partner_id')
def onchange_partner_id(self):
    self.vehicle_tags = None
    self.vehicle_tags = self.partner_id.id
```

The problem I am facing is that I want to fetch vehicles as per customers but it shows all vehicles in all customers. How can I fetch vehicles which specifically belongs to selected cusotmer only ??

I used the domain it shows empty as shown in below image :

[image: After Adding Domain]

res.partner.line code :

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class CustomContacts(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.partner"

x_brand_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner.line', 'x_brand_id', string="Brand Name")
x_model_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_model_id', string="Model Name")
x_customer_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_customer_id', string="Vehicle Details")

color = fields.Integer(string="Color")  # color_toggle



class CustomContactsPage(models.Model):

_name = "res.partner.line"
_rec_name = 'name'

x_customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Vehicle Details")
x_brand_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.brand', string="Brand Name")
x_model_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.model', string="Model Name")    
name = fields.Many2one('vehicle.number',string="Vehicle Number")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add domain in vehicle_tag field

`vehicle_tags = fields.Many2one('res.partner.line', string="Vehicles",domain="[('partner_id','=',partner_id)")`

partner_id field in left side of domain should be the field that has many2one relation in `res.partner.line` model you may have named it differently so change it accordingly

This should only show vehicles of a selected partner in the drop-down as the domain is added to check if the selected partner id and the partner id related to the vehicles are the same

You might see empty value in the vehicles field if the partner is not selected
[image: Added the suggestion in my code]

```
class CustomContacts(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    x_brand_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner.line', 'x_brand_id', string="Brand Name")
    x_model_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_model_id', string="Model Name")
    x_customer_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_customer_id', string="Vehicle Details")

class CustomContactsPage(models.Model):
    _name = "res.partner.line"
    _rec_name = 'name'
    x_customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Vehicle Details")
    x_brand_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.brand', string="Brand Name")
    x_model_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.model', string="Model Name")
    name = fields.Many2one('vehicle.number',string="Vehicle Number")
    
class VehicleNumber(models.Model):
    _name = "vehicle.number"
    name = fields.Char("Vehicle")
    
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    vehicle_tags = fields.Many2one('res.partner.line', string="Vehicles",domain="[('x_customer_id','=',partner_id)]")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , I added the domain as you said but it shows nothing in that field even if i selected the customer which has 4 vehicles added. I added the image above in question by editing the question , please check !

Comment: Please add code of res.partner.line model and also the condition that is added in the field

Comment: I have added the res.partner.line code below and also added the domain in vehicle tags check it.

Comment: `('x_customer_id','=',partner_id)` use this condition